# Python, scope of instance method variable in a class

Tags: python

From the below Python snippet code, variable `z` is local to `method_1()` and this shouldn't be accessed out of this method, but how this can be accessed from `method_2()`?

If I call `method_2()` it will print z value.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=100                               
        self.y=200

    def method_1(self):
        self.z=self.x+self.y                     # This variable has been created in method_1.

    def method_2(self):
        print("Z value from method_1:",self.z)   # Accessing z value in method_2

t1=Test()
t1.method_1()
t1.method_2()
```

Comment: `z` is not a local variable. It's an attribute of `self`. That's what `self.z` means.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question, in specific what makes you think z is local to nethod_1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` always refers to the actual instance of a class. So in your case even if you lazily declare a variable on `self` in a method, after it is declared it is accessible by any method bound to `self`, i.e. they share the same state.

There is no local instance scope in Python classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it in `method_2` because you defined it on `self`. It means it is an instance variable and it can be accessed inside that instance.